# Return and log of the same variable don't match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array named bars that contains the active id numbers of progress bars. I want to go through this array to find the first value that does not match its index (for finding the lowest available ID). My (apparently incorrect) solution is as follows:

```
var bars = [0,1];
function getNewBarID(counter) {
  var i = counter || 0; //sets i to counter value if it exists, or to 0 if it doesn't
  if (bars[i] == i) {
    ++i;
    getNewBarID(i);
  } else {
    console.log(i);
    return i;
  }
}
getNewBarID();
```

When I run this (in a node console and in chrome js console) it logs `2` to the console and returns `undefined`, while it should return `2`.

what!?

edit: when the function is run with an empty array, it both returns and logs `0` (more what!?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably:

```
return getNewBarID(i);
```

But to be honest it should rather be:

```
const newBar = bars.find((el,i) => el !== i) || bars.length; //newBar contains the result...
```

or a bit longer using a good old for loop:

```
function getNewBarID(){
  let i = 0;
  while(bars[i] === i) i++;
  return i;
}
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/zuqeqejoju/edit?console)

Comment: Life was never easy as your solution :P

Answer (score 0):

That is because you first run

```
getNewBarID();
```

where

```
if (bars[i] == i)
```

is true. From there you make the next call, yes, but the first call executes without a return value. You get a return value eventually, however first you executed twice without returning anything. Just add a return to the if-case:

```
return getNewBarID(i);
```

Comment: Dammit, always too late.